# remove randomly chosen elements from array

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, random

How can I do the following in Python?

- begin with linear array, `x`, and associated probability density function (pdf) `p(x)`
- remove `N` elements randomly, as specified by `p(x)`
- return `x` with selected elements removed (`x` will be shorter)
- return new array of N elements, **in order they were chosen**

caveat: array `x` may have repeated values, `xi`, that nevertheless have different probabilities (`p(x)` actually depends on parameters I'm not showing), so I want to be sure to remove the "correct" one that was chosen, not just elements that share the same value `xi`.

My code thusfar:

```
import numpy as np

N = 5;
x = np.linspace(0,5,11)
pdf = np.exp(-x**2);
pdf = pdf/np.sum(pdf);

x_rand_sorted = np.random.choice(x,N,replace=False,p = pdf)

print 'x:',x
print 'first N random elements:', x_rand_sorted
print 'x without random elements = ??'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outputs:

- remaining values:    `x_remaining`
- `N` random elements: `x_rand_vals`
- random element indices:`randices`

Example:

```
import numpy as np
N = 9;
n = 4;
x = np.linspace(0,2,N);
pdf = np.exp(-x**2);
pdf = pdf/np.sum(pdf);

#create mask, choose random indices from x according to pdf, set chosen indices to True:
indices = np.full(x.shape, False, bool)
randices = np.random.choice(np.arange(indices.shape[0]), n, replace = False,p = pdf)
indices[randices] = True

x_rand_vals = x[randices]
x_remaining = x[~indices]

np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
print 'original x:\t\t', x
print 'pdf array:\t\t', pdf
print 'random indices:\t\t',randices
print 'random values:\t\t',x_rand_vals
print 'remaining array:\t',x_remaining
```

(example output):

```
    original x:         [ 0.   0.2  0.4  0.6  0.8  1.   1.2  1.4  1.6  1.8  2. ]
    random indices:     [4 2 5]
    random values:      [ 0.8  0.4  1. ]
    remaining array:    [ 0.   0.2  0.6  1.2  1.4  1.6  1.8  2. ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boolean mask:

```
import numpy as np

N = 5;
x = np.linspace(0,5,11)
pdf = np.exp(-x**2);
pdf = pdf/np.sum(pdf);

index = np.full(x.shape, False, bool)
index[np.random.choice(np.arange(index.shape[0]), N, replace = False,p = pdf)] = True

x_rand_sorted = x[index]
x_rand_remaining = x[~index]

print 'x:',x
print 'first N random elements:', x_rand_sorted
print 'x without random elements: ', x_rand_remaining
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  If you can find a concise example of repeated values but different indices (and probabilities) that would be great.

Comment: No problem. Letting `x = np.random.randint(10, size = 11)` will guarantee a duplicate. Also, a trivial example is `x = np.full(10, 0)`.